# Issue importing CSV file with Logstash

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have a CSV file, and I want to import it in my Elastic Search.

I am on Windows 10 and I also have a Kibana be able to browse data once imported. I use Logstash to try to make this import.

**All of my services (Kibana, ES and Logstash) are running on my localhost.**

I tried with a the following Logstash configuration file (my csv file is in the correct path):

```
input {
  file {
    path => ["E:\Programmes\Logstash\logstash-2.2.0\data\*.csv"]
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter {
  csv {
    columns => ["billing_entity","invoice","company","username","reference","line_number","recipient_number","zone","network","date","time","country","duration","cost","currency","call_origin","billing_type"]
    separator => ";"
  }

  #grok {
  # match => { "call" => "%{WORD:billing_entity} %{WORD:invoice} %{WORD:company} %{WORD:username} %{WORD:reference} %{NUMBER:line_number} %{NUMBER:recipient_number} %{WORD:zone} %{WORD:network} %{DATE:date} %{TIME:time} %{WORD:country} %{WORD:duration} %{NUMBER:cost} %{WORD:currency} %{WORD:call_origin} %{WORD:billing_type}" }
  #}
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    action => "index"
    index => "call_samples"
    #index => "call-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    hosts => "localhost"
    workers => 1
  }
}
```

As you can see I tried to use '*csv*' or '*grok*' filter.

Then I launched in verbose mode logstash with this configuration file :

```
logstash.bat -f ..\conf\logstash.conf -v > logfile.txt
```

**EDIT** : after each try, I delete the generated sincedb files to simulate changes. But anyway I noticed they are empty

But in the logs I see nothing relevant :

> message=>"Using mapping template from"
>   message=>"Attempting to install template"
>   message=>"New Elasticsearch output"
>   message=>"Registering file input"
>   message=>"No sincedb_path set,generating o.... 
>   message=>"Using mapping template from ...
>   message=>"Attempting to install template"
>   message=>"New Elasticsearch output"
>   message=>"Starting pipeline"
>   message=>"Pipeline started"

Quite alike my file is ignored .... I also tried several indexes , etc ... it will never import data.

To check if data is present I make query on localhost:9200 or I browse Kibana search bar "Index name or pattern" with the index "call_samples".

Can anyone help me on this please ? I'm stuck at this point ... Thanks

**EDIT 2** :
Ok I'm dumb on this one, I just wanted to redirect the logs streams to a file when I was launching logstash :

```
logstash.bat -f ..\conf\logstash.conf -v > logfile.txt
```

But it was probably breaking the input file from being imported. So I just removed the part where I redirect on file :

```
logstash.bat -f ..\conf\logstash.conf -v
```

Now, my index is correctly created, but no data is being imported ...

Comment: If you've run this more than once, logstash has remembered the earlier run and sees nothing new to process.  You'll need to find your registry file (.sincedb*) and edit/remove it.

Comment: @Alain Collins oh yeah I forgot to say that I regulary delete the sincedb files created on my User context directory (C:\Users\myusername), so I think it see changes :/ Or maybe there are stored in another location too ?

Answer (score 0):

It was an encoding issue, and even in verbose mode, it never told me it was failing or something ... not even a little clue.

So I tested with a new test file encoded in UTF-8 and it worked well ...